# How to get min value from mySql but besed on Relational_ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySql

> Table Name - **T_Price**

```
ID  R_ID    Price
1   ID001   15700
2   ID001   16200
3   ID001   16400
6   ID002   15701
7   ID002   16201
8   ID002   16401
```

I have to get the lowest value but i am not be able to get 
i have tried below query but it is showing me only one record, but i want show every R_ID's lowest value

```
SELECT P.*
From price P  
Where P.price = (select MIN(price) from t_price)
```

**But above query is showing me only this**

```
ID  R_ID    Price
1   ID001   15700
```

**Record i want**

```
ID  R_ID    Price
1   ID001   15700
6   ID002   15701
```

Comment: @Strawberry  even when are similar, that question is for `I would like to get each user's highest score.` this is `all the record for the highscore user.`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza This question has been asked and (correctly) answered 100,000 times.

Comment: @Strawberry I know, I just saying the one you use to close solve a different question. So can be confusing for OP try to solve his problem.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry so how can i close the question

Comment: @User97798 The question is already closed, dont worry.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza perhaps - SO's duplicate algorithm isn't very good.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  no issue sir  i just  figured it out

Comment: easy solution:  `SELECT * FROM T_Price P
WHERE P.R_ID = (SELECT T.R_ID FROM T_Price T ORDER BY T.Price DESC limit 1)`

Comment: I just realize you make a typo on your wanted result. row 6 was `ID002` and you wrote `ID001` now the duplicated answer is exact what you need.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza sir it is not working there is showing all record of ID001 except then min record and not showing any of ID002

Comment: I told you I answer the question before fix the typo. That make the question totally different.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sir i am unable to get the correct value what can i do.

Comment: why? you say was already solve ?

Comment: If you still have problem make a new quesition show us what you have try and what error you got.

Comment: i have tried this [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B74WYUnqb4GcczRDcE5RV3lUM3M/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: prepare something like [this](http://rextester.com/GPN7115) db schema, sample data and current query.